# Quantifying the amount of information contributed by a single random variable

Tags: probability, information-theory

I have a random variable $U$ that is a function of individual binary random variables U_i's as follows:
$U = \sum_{i=1}^N A_iU_i + B_i(1 - U_i)$

The $U_i$'s are all independent of one another, but they are not identical. The probabilities $P(U_i = 1)$ and $P(U_i = 0)$ are fixed for all $U_i$'s.

Now, instead of getting data from all N $U_i$'s, I have to select a set of $n (n < N)$ number of $U_i$'s. The objective is to approximate the value of $U$ as closely as possible, but using only $n$ number of $U_i$'s. In other words, I am looking to reduce the absolute deviation between $U$ (that uses N sensors) and $\hat{U}$ (that uses $n$ sensors). Then, which $U_i$'s should be selected in this case? Is there any way of measuring the amount of "information" given by a particular $U_i$?

I have looked at Fisher information and Shannon information, but I am not sure how to actually quantify the "information" given by a single $U_i$. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: What are $A_i$ and $B_i$?

Comment: $A_i$ and $B_i$ are real constants (can be positive or negative). I am assuming that the amount of information contributed by $U_i$ will be in terms of $A_i$ and $B_i$.

Comment: @Arani How do you define two random variables as "close"?

Comment: @Stelios On an average, the difference between $U$ obtained using N sensors, and the one obtained using n sensors should be as small as possible.

Comment: So you prefer to minimise the absolute deviation instead of the square deviation? (Either choice is fine, but most people prefer square deviation to penalise large errors.)

Comment: @mlc Yes, I am looking at minimizing absolute deviation.

Comment: What is known about $U_i$? Since you talk about sensors, can we assume they are i.i.d.?

Comment: @mlc $U_i$'s are all independent, but not identical. Their probabilities of being 1's and 0's are different.

Comment: That means they have the same support, and this is useful. Do we know the probability that $U_i =1$ for a given $U_i$? Stating all assumptions upfront attracts better answers.

Comment: @mlc Yes, the probability of $U_i = 1$ and $U_i = 0$ are known for all $U_i$. I agree about the assumptions, and will add them to the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Yikai No, I want to minimize $E(|U - \hat{U}|)$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved using a variance criterion.

Let $U = \sum_{i=1}^N A_iU_i + B_i(1 - U_i)= \sum_{i=1}^N (A_i-B_i)U_i + B_i$ with $U_i$, $N$ independent Bernoulli random variables with known parameter $p_i$. Then
$$
V(U) = \sum_{i=1}^N (A_i-B_i)^2 V(U_i)
$$

If $U^n$ denote the best approximation of $U$, it can be obtained by selecting among
the values $(A_i-B_i)^2 V(U_i),\, i=1,\ldots N$ the $n$ greatest.

Comment: Can you please explain the intuition why variance is important here? Should it not be the sum of magnitudes of $A_i$ and $B_i$'s in some form? I am saying this because higher the value of $A_i$'s and $B_i$'s, the greater is its effect on $U$. Then, why is variance relevant? Thanks for responding.

Comment: @arani In most regression problem the least square criterion is used. $U^n$ is minimizing the criterion $V(U-U^n)$. The magnitude of $A_i$ and $B_i$ is captured by the quantity $(A_i-B_i)^2$